# Array of times find one that is 15 min before set time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to send out automated emails by at timestamp.  I have a set of unix timestamps in a DB.  I pull them then try and compare them to each other.  The part that breaks at the end. The foreach doesn't return the correct eblast id's. I think I am subtracting the unix timestamps correctly but I am not sure. I want the if statement to only fire if the timestamp from the DB is 15 minutes before the now timestamp. I only want it to fire when if its anytime before 15 minutes of the timestamp from the DB.  If its after the timestamp from the DB then do nothing. Hopefully that makes sense.

```
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'DB.php';

$timestamp = time();

echo 'Timestamp:';
echo $timestamp;
echo '------';

$drop_dead = mysql_query("SELECT due_date, ID FROM eblasts") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($drop_dead, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $final_email_id[$row[1]] = $row[0];
};

//this is the ID's of eblasts that need an email sent based on their drop_dead NOT on warning1, warning2 and due_date.
print_r($final_email_id);

foreach($final_email_id as $key => $value) {
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT warning_1 FROM eblasts WHERE ID = '$key'") or die(mysql_error());
 $find_warning_1 = mysql_fetch_row($query);
 $warning_1[$key] = $find_warning_1[0];
}
//this is the warning_1 numbers where the ID's of the array are the ID's of the eblast.
print_r($warning_1);

foreach($final_email_id as $key => $value) {
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT warning_2 FROM eblasts WHERE ID = '$key'") or die(mysql_error());
 $find_warning_2 = mysql_fetch_row($query);
 $warning_2[$key] = $find_warning_2[0];
}

//this is the warning_2 numbers where the ID's of the array are the ID's of the eblast.
print_r($warning_2);

foreach($final_email_id as $key => $value) {
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT due_date FROM eblasts WHERE ID = '$key'") or die(mysql_error());
 $find_due_date = mysql_fetch_row($query);
 $due_date[$key] = $find_due_date[0];
}

//this is the due date numbers where the ID's of the array are the ID's of the eblast.
print_r($due_date);

//Add 900 because its 15 minutes in seconds ... 
$run_time = $timestamp + 900;

foreach($warning_1 as $key => $value){
 $diff_time = $run_time - $warning_1[$key];
 echo '-----';
 echo $diff_time;
 echo '-----';
 if($diff_time < 900 && $diff_time > 0){
 echo 'different';
 echo $diff_time;
 $_SESSION['eblast_id'] = $key;
 include 'warning_1.php'; 
 }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `warning_x` fields are timestamps, too, this should do the trick:

```
$timestamp = time();

$query = sprintf(
    'SELECT id, warning_1' .
     ' FROM eblast' .
    ' WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(warning_1) - %u) BETWEEN 1 AND 899',
    $timestamp
);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $ids[$row[0]] = $row[1];
};

var_dump($ids);
...
```

Comment: Nice - BUT where the mysql server and the server running the DB are not in the same time zone AND I did a set timezone to CST at the beginning of the script ... doesn't that screw with things?

Comment: Yes, that could cause some problems, depending on the DB's config. I've updated my post to reflect that.

Comment: +1 - do it in the db, not in PHP.  Your life will be easier if you always work with UTC timestamps and convert time zones when doing input/output to the user.

Comment: @El Yobo You're right, the DB is generally the right place to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you modify your first SQL query to only select records with a timestamp column less than the current time minus 15 minute's worth of seconds?